# References on Lie Group Double Coverings

Tags: topological-groups

I am currently studying spin geometry and when dealing with the spin groups I came across the notion of a "Lie group double covering", but the book I am following does not define this notion and I couldn't find a reference on this topic. Could someone point me to such a reference?

Comment: It just means you have a 2-to-1 surjective homomorphism of Lie groups. In your context the groups are Spin(n) and SO(n).